# Laravel Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple function which dumps the current user id from database. This should be working but it is throwing 'Trying to get property id of non-object' currently.

UploadController.php

```
public function getUserId(){
    $currentuser = auth()->user();
    $userid = $currentuser->id;
    //$userid = Auth::user()->id;
    dd($userid);
}
```

Using both auth()->user() and Auth::user() function dumps the error. Any solution please?

Comment: Are you sure there is a looged in user? if no user logged in, `user()` will be null, and `user()->id` will throw an error

Comment: please try to run dd(auth()) at first

Comment: `auth()->id()` will return the id. Make sure you are auth'd first

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I wasn't logged in in the first place, so it was throwing error. Thanks for the help all of you